# How to add Django template tags in a different Js file

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

Hi I want to add the tag `{{request.user.first_name}}` in my js code. I am aware that if the js code is within the HTML document you can easily add any Django template tag in Django version 3.2.

But for now, my HTML is as such...

```
<script src="{% static 'dashboard/driver.js' %}"></script>
```

Which contains over 2000 lines, and I do not want to include it in my HTML file.

So my question is can I add the tag `{{request.user.first_name}}` and several others in a separate JS file, in my case `driver.js`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add any Django template code in `js` file directly.

There are 3 ways you can add the `first_name` in js file.

1. Write a django `ajax` views and call the api for `first_name` from your js file as soon as your page is loaded. or
2. render your first name in your html file hidden `input` fields and than grab the fields value it's name or id from your `js`file or
3. put a utill function on your html js `<sccript>` tags which are gonna call you `driver.js` file related method.